# Identifying BufferGeometry sides

Tags: three.js

I'm loading an object from `.obj` & `.mtl` files. It looks like this:

[image: bag]

What I'm trying to achieve here is that I want to be-able to identify each of the different sides on the bag so I can change each sides colour individually.

I've examined the object and it contains the following:

[image: THREE.Group]

I've tried to create an array of uniquely coloured materials and apply them like so:

```
var materials = [
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x80ffaa}),     // Light green
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xe60000}),     // Red
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xff4dff}),     // Pink
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x3399ff}),     // Light blue
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xac7339}),   // Brown
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x666699})    // Purple
        ];
        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)
        this.selectedProduct[0]['children'][0].material.materials = materials;
```

but it appeared like so:

[image: coloured bag]

So only three colours were applied to it. The model I'm using is exported out of Blender and so that's where I get my `.obj` & `.mtl` files and in the `.mtl` file it only applies three materials.

So how do I go about getting and updating each side?

**EDIT**
@pailhead
I've examined the object in Blender and as far as I can see, each of those sides should be unique. Here's the edit view of the object:

[image: edit view of the bags]

So I should be-able to apply a different material to each side then right?

**EDIT 2**

I'm confused as to what's happening here. I've merged the lip of the bag with the side it was one to create one side each for the bigger sides. Applying the same materials and colour I get this:[image]

The side under each of the handles is one side only - so why am I getting two different colours appearing?

Comment: How do you know that the model contains a description of the sides the way you want them and not some other way? For example, it could only be separated in three sides, not 6 or whatever you expect. You need to handle this in blender, perhaps export 6 different things and name them the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to apply six different materials to a model, and saw only three as a result.

What would have happened if you decided that you needed to provide 7 different materials, or 12 or even 2? The information that should describe whether this model has 3 "different sides" or 6 or 9 is in the .obj file, which does not change no matter how many different materials you apply with three.js.

Is it safe to assume that **this particular obj** only holds enough information to distinguish between three **different faces**? I'd say so.

This means that you need to create a different model describing the material relations differently. Go back to blender, assign more ids, or break the mesh apart into "sides" and you'll have logical entities to work with.

Otherwise, you can extract sub meshes out of your geometry. This is complicated but you could build a structure that would allow you to walk the faces. You could then set some kind of thresholds of rules as to where the boundaries should be (like, extract everything that is less than 45 degrees away from the +Y axis, and is connected to face 563).

Comment: I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that the sides are unique? Do they exist as separate entities in blender? I only have experience with the 3ds max json exporter. The same set of meshes can be exported differently depending on what kind of materials are applied, but not sure how it works in blender.

Comment: Also, think about it from a logical standpoint. Do you see those faces that make the corners look rounded. They are triangles just as everything else. That's why when you say "side" it is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks @pailhead. The problem actually had to do with the object itself as you suggested. To assign a different material to each side required me to create objects out of the required sides that I needed. For example - the front, back, right and left sides are treated as their own individual object in the mesh. I don't recall exactly how I did it but will find the question and link to it here. +1 for the aid.